# MMX assist for overriding methods

Tags: delphi-ide

Using the MMX add-in for the Delphi IDE, is there a way to display a list of virtual methods that can be overridden in the current class, similar to the way MMX can show me interface methods that can be implemented in the current class? Forgive me if this is obvious, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks

David

Comment: This is unlikely related to the "Pentium MMX technology" (I don't know which MMX you are referring to, or if there is a tag for that)

Comment: This question is about Model Maker, an add-on for Delphi that is abbreviated MMX.

Comment: There seems to be no tag for that. I removed the [mmx] tag, since it will attract unrelated people (such as myself ^^)